# Error d'initialization pyproj

Tags: python, geopandas

I have an Access database(.mdb) and I want to create a shape points from this database by using a library of GeoPandas. My script is working properly, but recently I encountered this problem after re-installation of GeoPandas

> error messages : pyproj._data_dir does not export C function pyproj_context_initialize

How can I fix this error which resulted in importation of GeoPandas?

[image]

Comment: Did you try to upgrade or downgrade `pyproj`?

Comment: pyproj is with same version before re-installation of GeoPandas